# How can i read parquet files in my ADLS Gen 1 from PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, parquet, azure-data-lake

Is there a connector to read parquet files that exist in my ADLS Gen 1 storage from PowerBI and make reports?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: If so,could you please mark it which is beneficial for others on the forum.Thx.

Answer (score 2):

According to below feedbacks, parquet format is not supported in PB so far:

1.https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15181038-support-avro-file-format

2.https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/30976708-parquet-format-support-for-direct-import-from-azur

[image]

There is a payware named [Data Virtuality Pipes](https://datavirtuality.com/connectors/visualize/parquet-file/microsoft-power-bi/) which is applied for the parquet files integration with PB.

In my opinion,i'd recommand you still staying in the azure ecosystem.You could see that [ADF copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-data-movement-activities#supported-file-formats) supports ***Text, JSON, Avro, ORC, and Parquet*** so that you could use it to load your data into azure blob storage(which costs not too much).Then you could follow this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/azure-blob-storage-integration-with-power-bi) to integrate storage account with PB.

Answer (score 0):

since you are already on Azure , you can try Azure Synapse( known as SQL DW previously) polybase feature. You can create external table pointing to adls gen2  parquet and then connect PowerBI without need of Data Gateway. with other solutions like Data Virtuality , Dremio (https://www.dremio.com/on-prem/) or apache drill , you will need a onpremises data gateway. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect to Amazon Athena databases from Power BI using ODBC
As far as I know, Amazon Athena has JDBC/ODBC drivers so front-end reporting tools like Power BI can connect to Amazon Athena where S3 bucket files can be easily mapped as tables